# How to hide part of intersection in Solidworks?

Tags: solidworks

I have imported `STL` into Solidworks, converted it, then built an intersection of this body with a plane. I got 3 objects: first half of a body, second half of a body and an intersection ellipse.

I can select any of these parts:

[image]

On this picture I have selected one half and hovered ellipse.

I would like to sketch in a plane, having this ellipse as a reference.

Unfortunately, the halfs of the body occlude sketch for me. Hence I would like to hide them, but can't: deselecting `eye` icon hides entire body and an ellipse.

How to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below - expand the side bar and the solid bodies folder, to then individually hide solid bodies.

You can use the same side bar to quickly toggle visiblity of Sketches, Planes, Axes etc., too

[image]